# How to remove border with iframe on IE10

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, border

I'm making this website: www.comblemine.ch
And I have a blue border on IE 10 that I cannot remove, even using the `frameBorder="0"` and/or a script like this one:

```
if (window.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"))
   {
      var iFrameElements = window.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
      for (var i = 0; i < iFrameElements.length; i++)
         {
            iFrameElements[i].frameBorder="0";   //  For other browsers.
            iFrameElements[i].setAttribute("frameBorder", "0");   //  For other browsers (just a backup for the above).
            iFrameElements[i].contentWindow.document.body.style.border="none";   //  For IE.
         }
   }
```

The website is made with Wordpress and I use Advance_Iframe plugin.
I use netrenderer to render the version of my website on IE10.

On IE too, I cannot acces all the submenu because the iframe is above them, even using: `z-index` in the CSS.

Anyway to remove this border and change the index of my iframe ?

HTML of the iframe:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr" xml:lang="fr">


 <head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
  <title>comblemine</title>
</head>

<body>

    <img class="img" src="./img/autres_pages/accueil.png"  width="600" alt="" style="display:block ;position:absolute;left:20%;top:0%;" usemap="#Map" id="back" >


    <div class="txtGauche" id="textGauche" 
        style="display:block ; 
        position:absolute ; 
        left:15% ;
        top:9%;
        width:14rem; 
        height: 25rem;
        color:#fff; 
        background-color: rgba(143, 143, 143, 0.5); 
        z-index:9999 ; 
        padding-top:10px; 
        padding-right:20px; 
        padding-bottom:15px; 
        padding-left:20px;
        font-family:Frutiger, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 87%;">
        <p>



        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="txtDroit" id="textDroit" style="display:block ; 
        position:absolute ; 
        right:8% ;
        top:9%;
        width:14rem; 
        height: 25rem;
        color:#fff; 
        background-color: rgba(143, 143, 143, 0.5); 
        z-index:9998 ; 
        padding-top:10px; 
        padding-right:20px; 
        padding-bottom:15px; 
        padding-left:20px; 
        font-family:Frutiger, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 87%;">
            <p>

        </p>

    </div>
```

HTML of the main page (the important part)

```
<iframe id='iframe' name='iframe'  src='http://www.comblemine.ch/wp-content/themes/padhang_Modif/accueil.php'  width='100%'  height='600'  scrolling='no'  frameBorder=0  border='0'  seamless='seamless'  allowtransparency='true'  onload='jQuery(&quot;#iframe&quot;).css(&quot;visibility&quot;, &quot;visible&quot;);' ></iframe>
```

The CSS I use for that:

```
iframe{
    border: 0;
}
```

And the script at the top of the main page:

```
 <script>

 if (document.getElementById("iframe"))
   {
      var iFrameElements = document.getElementById("iframe");
      for (var i = 0; i < iFrameElements.length; i++)
         {
            iFrameElements[i].frameBorder="0";   //  For other browsers.
            iFrameElements[i].setAttribute("frameBorder", 0);   //  For other browsers (just a backup for the above).
            iFrameElements[i].contentWindow.document.body.style.border="none";   //  For IE.
         }
   }

 </script>
```

Comment: Please post HTML and CSS.

Comment: Added it, hope it's enough

Comment: Get them DB creds out of there.  While it's just your local, you NEVER want to accidentally post DB access creds.  You should also consider using mysqli_ instead of mysql_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Completly forgot them, sorry. Yes, I just had some issus with mysqli_ so using mysql_ for not be blocked